# Influxdb Setup: connection refused

Tags: linux, influxdb, influxdb-2

I am trying to install and setup InfluxDB OSS 2.7 on a Ubuntu 22.04 machine hosted in AWS Lightsail. I am able to install everything but when I try to set up the admin user, the connection is refused.

I installed [influxd](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.7/install/?t=Linux#manually-download-and-install-the-influxd-binary). Then I ran `influxd` to start the server. Next I installed the [influx client](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.7/tools/influx-cli/?t=Linux#download-from-the-command-line). Then I try to [setup influx](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.7/install/?t=Set+up+with+the+CLI#set-up-influxdb-through-the-influx-cli) but the connection is refused.

Here is the setup command I'm running:

`influx setup --username superuser --password FakePassword --org MyOrg --bucket MyBucket --force`

That produces this error message:

Error: failed to check if already set up: Get "http://localhost:8086/api/v2/setup": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8086: connect: connection refused

Any ideas what is going on here?